# Change error field name in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm wondering if there's a way to change the field name for a validation error it's associated with. For example, if I submit First Name (really `fname` in the table) without any data, it yells `Fname can't be blank.`

Is it possible to change this to `First Name can't be blank`?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The general practice now-a-days is to edit your [locals](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models) like so:

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        fname: "First Name"
```

Your error message will now say "First Name can't be..."

For completeness sake, you have another option. Which is to add the following to your User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES = {
    :fname => "First Name"
  }

  def self.human_attribute_name(attr, options = {}) # 'options' wasn't available in Rails 3, and prior versions.
    HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES[attr.to_sym] || super
  end

end
```

Comment: +1. But I think the `def self.human_attribute_name(attr)` is not required.

Comment: in Rails 4 I had to add a second argument to `self.human_attribute_name(attr)` method call. So it becomes `self.human_attribute_name(attr, options = {})`

Comment: In some casese you need to change activerecord to activemodel

`en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        fname: "First Name"`