# Rails change validation attribute name in ajax response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, validation

I have a rails application that sends validation error messages to another site after a form is submitted from that site.

I have lots of columns I need to customize but for now I'm just trying to get one working properly. I'm trying to get it working by changing en.yml.

```
#config/locales/en.yml

en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      message:
        msg_from_name:
          one: "Your Name"
```

The validation is being called on the Message model.

```
#app/models/message.rb

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :msg_from_name, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 20 }
end
```

Right now when the `msg_from_name` is validated it returns:
"msg_from_name is too short (minimum is 3 characters)"

What I'm trying to get is:
"Your Name is too short (minimum is 3 characters)"

How do I change the attribute name rails sends to the external site during validation?

**Updated** change from comments that is still not working:
[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785503/change-error-field-name-in-rails)

```
#config/locales/en.yml
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      message:
        msg_from_name: "Your Name"
```

And when I try:

```
#app/models/message.rb

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :msg_from_name, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 20 }

  HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES = {
    :msg_from_name => "First Name"
  }

  #Rails 4
  def self.human_attribute_name(attr, options = {})
    HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES[attr.to_sym] || super
  end
end
```

I get the same output again. I'm not sure if the syntax I'm using only applies to the view or if the code required for the view is different than what gets sent as errors in ajax to an external site.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785503/change-error-field-name-in-rails

Comment: @pitabasprathal Thanks for the ref. I updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not sure why what I tried doesn't work when sending back ajax to another site but works in local view, I did the following to fix my issue.

The client side on the external site could already catch HTTP status errors (400, 402, 500, etc) with `response.status` and `response.statusText`. I was sending validation errors by pushing them into a hash `errors[:codeErrors]` and building an array of failed validation messages. Clients could access them with `response.responseJSON.codeErrors`. Example code:

```
//external sites clientform.js
  ...
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: '//example.com/page', //target url
    data: $('#contact-form').serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
      // ...
    },
    error: function(response) {
      console.log("Error: " + response.status + ", Message: " + response.statusText)
      // Custom server errors
      var msg = response.responseJSON.codeErrors;
      console.log("There are " + msg.length + " validation errors:")
      for(i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) console.log(msg[i]);
    }
  });
  e.preventDefault();
  ...
```

So I replaced the text in each string before sending the ajax response to the client:

```
# rails controller
...
errors[:codeErrors].each do |text| 
  text.sub! 'msg_from_site', 'Form Origin'
  text.sub! 'msg_from_name', 'Your Name'
  text.sub! 'msg_from_ipaddress', 'IP Error'
  # ...etc
end

render status: statusCode, json: errors
...
```

I'm sure this isn't the best way but it's the only way I could make work.