# Custom model name in Rails 4 validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a class that looks something like this:

```
class OrganicBipedalLifeform < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Has the field 'name'

  validate :presence_of_name

  private

  def presence_of_name
    errors.add(:base, "name can't be blank") unless name.present?
  end
end
```

And I want the validation error message to use a custom string that excludes (or modifies) the model name, say 'Human/Vulcan name can't be blank'.

If I want this to be the default message for validation errors on this model, is there a better approach than changing the flash details in every view which might display validation errors? Ie by changing something on the model itself?

Apologies if this has been answered elsewhere. I've found a lot of posts about customising the field name, but none about modifying the name of the model itself.

ETA: @TomDunning @Dan, I think I misidentified the source of the problem (or at least didn't make it sufficiently specific), so am creating a new thread to ask what I hope is a better question.

Comment: Where does "Human/Vulcan" come from? How does `OrganicBipedalLifeform` know what kind of thing you failed to provide a name?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can replace `:base` with `self.class_name` or `self.class.table_name` or a similar class method.

Comment: As with @TomDunning's answer, this doesn't change the model name - it interpolates another string after the model name.

Answer (score -1):

That is bad design, just use this:

`validate :name, presence: true`

"name can't be blank" would be the default error anyway.

If you then want to extract these later just call `my_record.errors` or similar.

For a custom error message

`validate :name, presence: { message: 'must not be blank' }`

Comment: The reason it's like that is because I'm trying to customise the message. But both doing it the way I wrote and the custom way you describe retain the (Rails-translated) object name. So eg the page would display 'Organic bipedal life forms name cannot be blank' rather than 'Human/Vulcan name cannot be blank'.

Comment: @Arepo that's not enough reason to move the error to base from the attribute in question. This is a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785503/change-error-field-name-in-rails

Comment: you may also want to look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#message for alternative ways to change the message